# identifying if image store is optimized for device

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I am using ALAssetsLibrary to access photo's. My app needs high resolution images. If the user enables iCloud and selects optimize image for the device when memory is low on device, the image is no longer high resolution.

Is originalAsset property in ALAsset the right one to identify this change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8 you can use PHImageManager to get full-sized image assets. Specifically, look at `requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:`  [See here for details.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:)

**EDIT:**

You can also use `requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:` with a `targetSize` of `PHImageManagerMaximumSize`